# How to make an event repeat on the third last working day of each month in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, apple-ical

Unfortunately my pay dates are a nightmare. I get paid on the third last working day at the end of each month. Here's a years worth of dates.

- 29/09/14
- 29/10/14
- 26/11/14
- 19/12/14 (exception due to christmas) this one can be ignored
- 28/01/15
- 25/02/15
- 27/03/15
- 28/04/15
- 27/05/15
- 26/06/15
- 29/07/15
- 26/08/15

Is this possible to do in Google Calendar or .ical format (RFC5545) and import? I've explored RRULE a bit, but can't find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

you can achieve this by leveraging the `RRULE` of the RFC5545.

To get the desired results, you need to define the fact that you get paid once a month `FREQ=MONTHLY` then defining the days of which you can get paid (monday, tuesday, ..., friday) using the property `BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR` and then specifying that you only get paid on the third last one `BYSETPOS=-3` the final RRULE then reads:

`FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-3`

you can see the results [here](http://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/#/rfc/FREQ=MONTHLY;WKST=MO;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-3)

Comment: How does one input these codes in Google Calendar?

Comment: You can follow these instructions http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/17531/50 to add to Google Calendar