# How to make a task repeat on the last day of each quarter in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I've successfully added a repeating event to the last day of every month using the below syntax:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20110731
DTEND:20110731
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA;BYSETPOS=-1;WKST=SU
SUMMARY:Name of your event
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

thanks to the advice of this article ([How to make a task repeat on the last day of each month in Google Calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/10929)) but I need to set up a quarterly repeating event.

Does anyone know how to edit frequency syntax so that the event repeats on the last day of the month every three months (or every x months)?

Answer (score 3):

Just add **INTERVAL=3;** to the repeating rule (RRULE)

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20110731
DTEND:20110731
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=3;BYDAY=SU,MO,TU,WE,TH,FR,SA;BYSETPOS=-1;WKST=SU
SUMMARY:Name of your event
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```